# Flask jsonify: how to escape characters

Tags: python, json, flask, xss

I have just started working with the Flask web framework.  I am currently writing an endpoint that returns bits of JSON that may very well contain malicious javascript.

For example:

```
@api.route("/tester")
def api_jobs_tester():
    return jsonify({
        "name": "<script>alert(1)</script>"
    })
```

In this example, this returns:

```
{
  "name": "<script>alert(1)</script>"
}
```

Ideally, however, I would like this to return:

```
{
  "name": "&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;"
}
```

Of course, this is straightfoward to do on a per-value, basis, with just:

```
return jsonify({
    "name": escape("<script>alert(1)</script>")
})
```

However, I may need to return much more complex JSON responses than this, in which I do not necessarily know before hand the structure of the JSON.

I could probably role my own function that traverses the JSON tree and escapes all the strings, but I would much prefer a built-in way of doing this.

What is the easiest way to escape the values in a JSON response using Flask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*jsonify* function haven't option for escaping. But there is *htmlsafe_dumps* function in flask.json which you can use:

```
from flask import json, jsonify

return jsonify(**json.loads(json.htmlsafe_dumps(obj)))
```

Comment: `htmlsafe_dumps` is very close to what I want.  However, there are a few issues:  1) Your imports don't match your code 2) `jsonify` can't wrap htmlsafe_dumps 3) `htmlsafe_dumps` returns the wrong content type.  If you can fix these, I'll be glad to accept this as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, this was small mistake. Now it should do what you need.

Comment: This fixes issue 1, but doesn't resolve issues 2 or 3.  `return jsonify(json.htmlsafe_dumps(obj))` causes a ValueError, because `json.htmlsafe_dumps` returns a unicode string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Now it have to work) I forgot that jsonify function requires list of parameters. So now we obtain python's dictionary from unicode string at first and break it up via ** operator.